# WeifenLuo(Dock Panel Suite) Dock to multiple dockpanels

Tags: c#, dock, dockpanel-suite

I use WeifenLuo DockPanel in my project. Now I have a main window (let's call it MAINWINDOW), and another window (let's call it SECONDWINDOW), both of them are holding a DockPanel (dockPanel1 and dockPanel2). I want to implement a feature: if I move a Document (DockState.Document) from MAINWINDOW to SECONDWINDOW, I want to make it possible to dock it. So basically I want to dock a DockContent from dockPanel1 to dockPanel2. Is it possible?
Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: If you are using this project https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite? I cannot found a good result for "WeifenLuo's dockPanel"

Comment: No intention to support that feature. As it is open source, you can hack on your own.